# How to get the list of events of specific facebook page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events

i am trying to get the list of all event that the specific page has on the Facebook, but i couldn't find this in their Graph API. there are several forums and stack posts but they couldn't help me. is there any other way or specific API for getting this information ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/event/

> Access to Events on Users and Pages is only available to Facebook Marketing Partners.